# Can anyone tell me why this loop isn't working as it should?

Tags: javascript

This is for an exercise on codewars.com. The idea is to make a function that takes an array as the first parameter, then deletes each item in sequence defined by the second parameter, so if the second parameter is 3, it'll delete 3 first(counting for this one is supposed to be 1 based, not 0 based), then 6, then 9, then back around to 2, as though all the items were in a circle, then 7 (because 3 and 6 are gone), etc, then return the items in the order in which they were deleted (this pattern is referred to as a Josephus permutation).

So here's my code:

```js
function josephus(items, k) {
  var arr = [];
  var l = items.length;
  var a = k - 1;
  for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    arr.push(items[a]);
    items.splice(a, 1);
    a += k - 1 ;
    if (a >= items.length) { a = a - items.length; }
  }
  return arr;
}
```

It works sometimes. It worked right with `josephus([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 1)`, but then with `josephus([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 2)`, it worked until the last number(5, in this case), then returned `null`. In fact, most times, it returns null in the place of the last item. Can anyone tell me why it's doing this? If you have a codewars account, you can try it out in its context here: http://www.codewars.com/kata/5550d638a99ddb113e0000a2/train/javascript

Comment: Its because after few iterations when length of array become smaller than 'k' it returns undefined as we don't have element on that index in reduced array.

Answer (score 0):

Your index re-calculation isn't working. i.e. a = 3, items = [1] `a` becomes 2, `items[2]` is undefined. Try this code:

```
function j(items,k){
  var arr = [];
  var l = items.length;
  var a = k - 1;
  for(var i = 0; i<l; i++){
    arr.push(items[a]);
    items.splice(a, 1);
    a += k - 1 ;
    a = a % items.length;
  }
  return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
arr.push(items[a]);
```

with

```
arr.push(items[a%items.length]);
```

Comment: I think you need to update code with the help of above code. Its working correctly upto 3 but not giving expected result for 4 and 5. Please check and let me know if you are able to solve this.